# Variable doesn't change in def

Tags: python

When i run this program (it should switch on and off the output every 3 sec), but the "enable" value stay 0 and doesn't change to 1 however during the def be() running. If you just try the progremyou will see only it write "on".
Please help, because i am beginner in python.

```
import threading
import os
import smbus
from threading import Timer
from time import sleep

bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # Rev 2 Pi uses 1

DEVICE = 0x20 # Device address (A0-A2)
IODIRA = 0x00 # Pin direction register
OLATA  = 0x14 # Register for outputs
GPIOA  = 0x12 # Register for inputs

bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,0)
enable = 0
beki = 1
be = 0
ki=0

def be():
     print "on"
     bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,1)
     sleep(0.2)
     enable=1
def ki():
     print "off"
     bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,0)
     sleep(0.1)
     enable=0

while True:

  if(enable==0):
     on = threading.Timer(3, be)
     on.start()
  if(enable==1):
     off = threading.Timer(3, ki)
     off.start()
  sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing a local variable in your functions. To change the global variable, you need to use the `global` keyword, e.g:

```
def be():
    global enable
    # ...
    enable = 1
```